# Script to Block and Unblock a Port

Tags: linux, port, block, iptables

```
root@node2:~# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports iscsi-target

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

How do I write a script to remove the rule which blocks the iscsi-target port (3260)? I've tried doing:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3260 -j ACCEPT
```

But all I accomplish is inserting a new rule, which does not unblock the port.

Using:

```
portblock::tcp::3260::unblock, from /etc/ha.d/haresources, does not remove the block to port 3260.
```

For now, I am using `iptables --flush` after `portblock::tcp::3260::block` to unblock port 3260.

Ultimately, I want to put up a firewall, which means I only want to temporary block port 3260 then, unblock it.

Can someone help me code a script that I can call to block port 3260 then, unblock it with another script?

Thanks,

JC

Answer (score 4):

If you use `-A`, you are appending to the chain therefore, any rule that matches in the chain previous to this one, will take precedence. You need to use `-I` to insert at the first position.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3260 -j ACCEPT
```

In fact, your default policy is ACCEPT but the very first rule in your chain is to DROP anything from any source to any destination which will always match anything that comes in the INPUT chain.

You should delete that rule with

```
iptables -D INPUT 1
```

And then you can Append the rule you want to add.

In conclusion, you can unblock port 2360 by simply inserting the rule at position 0 in the INPUT chain:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3260 -j ACCEPT
```

And block it again by deleting the same rule with `iptables -D INPUT 0`

By default, I think this is a good [set of rules](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables):

```
# iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
# iptables -F
# iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -P INPUT DROP
# iptables -P FORWARD DROP
# iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

You should check [this link](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables). There's a full script at the bottom that you can use to set up IPTables with a good set of rules which you can modify to your needs.

Comment: Rule numbering is 1-based therefore command for deleting the rule should be `iptables -D INPUT 1`